# MVC LINQ dynamic orderBy getting column type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic-typing

I am trying to dynamically order a list of products.

```
Product:
price (int)
name (string)
```

So far I have managed to get the following:

```
string columnToOrderBy = "price";
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
var ordering = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, double>>(Expression.Property(param, columnToOrderBy), param);
```

this works for ordering by price, however it won't work when ordering by name because of the column type.

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, double>>
```

Is there anyway to get the type of a column to set it in the Func method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Dynamic LINQ, Scott Gu did a great post on it here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It makes it as easy as this

```
query = query.OrderBy(columnName);
```

or

```
//orderby descending
query = query.OrderBy(columnName + " DESC");
```

There's no need to mess around with manually manipulating expression trees when you don't have to.  Using dynamic LINQ will make your code easier to understand and maintain.

---

### Edit

You can now install this as a Nuget package, but none of them seem to be from an official source (at the time of writing).

Here's a [vanilla package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) containing the code that Scott Gu presented.

Here's a [branch of Scott's code](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/) that has been expanded to include more features.  It appears to be under active development, and looks quite interesting.

Comment: That's great thanks! I came across it earlier but decided not to use it. I'm not sure why now!

Answer (score 0):

1. PM> Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic
2. query = query.OrderBy(columnName);